# Why is a vector of classes faster then class with vector

Tags: c++, performance, c++17

Hi tried the following example and dont understand why it is how it is.

Example first

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Ant {
private:
  int m_worker;

public:
  Ant(int x=0) : m_worker(x) {}

  int GetWorker() const {
      return m_worker;
  }
};

class AntFarm {
private:
  std::vector<int> m_worker;

public:
  AntFarm() : m_worker(100) {}

  int GetWorker(int index) const {
      return m_worker.at(index);
  }
};


int main() {
  AntFarm farm{};
  std::vector<Ant> vec(100);
  Timer timer_farm{};
  Timer timer_ant{};

  timer_farm.Start();
  for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
      for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
          int a = farm.GetWorker(i);   
      }
  }
  timer_farm.Stop();

  timer_ant.Start();
  for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
      for(const auto ant : vec) {
          int a = ant.GetWorker();
      }
  }
  timer_ant.Stop();

  std::cout << "Farm time passed = "<<timer_farm.Milliseconds() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Ant time passed = "<<timer_ant.Milliseconds() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Farm time passed = 30
Ant time passed = 2
```

I tried to model an Antfarm differently. First approach is to have an Ant as a class and store the Antfarm in an vector of Ant's. Second approach is to have an AntFarm class who has a vector of int's within.

Now when i call GetWorker i thought the first approach will be slower then the second. But turns out the first approach is why faster.

Can anyone explain why approach 1 is faster then approach 2?!

EDIT:

I compiled for Windows 10 x64 with MSCV compiler Version 16.9.0+5e4b48a27 and following compile options: /GT /GS /Gs /guard:cf $<$CONFIG:Debug:/RTC1>

Comment: You need to specify how you're compiling (OS, compiler, compiler version, switches used), along with the rest of a true [MCVE] (what is your timer class?). Odds are using `.at()` (which does bounds-checking) instead of `[]` (which doesn't) is responsible, but these are useless loops anyway, so a good optimizing compiler should compile them to absolutely nothing.

Comment: You are measuring the time taken by "toy" code that doesn't actually do any useful work. That will give misleading and often meaningless results.

Comment: Ok when i run that "toy" code under linux i got time passed=0 for both. When i changed the build type according to the answer of r_ahlskog i can observe the same cautious. But on windows it always prints the same times passed whatever i built in Debug or Release.

Answer (score 0):

I substituted my own timer class as you did not provide one so it prints in nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.

Running your code in release build produces

```
Farm time passed = 660100
Ant time passed = 0
```

So it obviously optimizes away your loop in the second case since it has no visible side effects in the first case it still does some work.

Changing your AntFarm::GetWorker to use array indexing instead of .at()

```
int GetWorker(int index) const {
    return m_worker[index];
}
```

gets us the expected result.

```
Farm time passed = 0
Ant time passed = 0
```

Now we can add in some visible side effects so that the code is actually run. I just moved a outside the loop and print it after we are done so it can't be optimized away.

```
timer_farm.Start();
int a;
for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        a = farm.GetWorker(i);
    }
}
timer_farm.Stop();
std::cout << a;

timer_ant.Start();
for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
    for(const auto ant : vec) {
        a = ant.GetWorker();
    }
}
timer_ant.Stop();
std::cout << a << "\n";
```

Now we get some results on both .at and []

```
m_worker[index]
Farm time passed = 109700
Ant time passed = 318600

m_worker.at(index)
Farm time passed = 550200
Ant time passed = 318200
```

So clearly using .at() on vector here costs more since it does bounds checking but using array syntax it is faster.

Comment: That still can be optimised to `timer_farm.Start(); timer_farm.Stop(); std::cout << farm.getWorker(99);` etc

Comment: @Caleth Very much true, I was a little surprised it didn't. I was typing it up on my lunch so I felt it was close enough to the truth.